# Refactor namespace in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class in a namespace that I've used extensively throughout my solution. As the number of classes in this namespace has grown I realize that it would've been a better design decision to place this class (and a few others) into a sub-namespace. Is there any easy way to do this in Visual Studio(C#)?

I'm thinking something like the Class->Refactor->Rename feature.

Perhaps an extension?