# How to organize unit tests and do not make refactoring a nightmare?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, code-organization

My current way of organizing unit tests boils down to the following:

- Each project has its own dedicated project with unit tests. For a project `BusinessLayer`, there is a `BusinessLayer.UnitTests` test project.
- For each class I want to test, there is a separate test class in the test project placed within exactly the same folder structure and in exactly the same namespace as the class under test. For a class `CustomerRepository` from a namespace `BusinessLayer.Repositories`, there is a test class `CustomerRepositoryTests` in a namespace `BusinessLayerUnitTests.Repositories`.

Methods within each test class follow simple naming convention `MethodName_Condition_ExpectedOutcome`. So the class `CustomerRepositoryTests` that contains tests for a class `CustomerRepository` with a `Get` method defined looks like the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CustomerRepositoryTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Get_WhenX_ThenRecordIsReturned()
    {
        // ...
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get_WhenY_ThenExceptionIsThrown()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This approach has served me quite well, because it makes locating tests for some piece of code really simple. On the opposite site, it makes code refactoring really more difficult then it should be:

- When I decide to split one project into multiple smaller ones, I also need to split my test project.
- When I want to change namespace of a class, I have to remember to change a namespace (and folder structure) of a test class as well.
- When I change name of a method, I have to go through all tests and change the name there, as well. Sure, I can use Search & Replace, but that is not very reliable. In the end, I still need to check the changes manually.

Is there some clever way of organizing unit tests that would still allow me to locate tests for a specific code quickly *and* at the same time lend itself more towards refactoring?

Alternatively, is there some, uh, perhaps Visual Studio extension, that would allow me to somehow say that "hey, *these* tests are for *that* method, so when name of the method changes, please be so kind and change the tests as well"? To be honest, I am seriously considering to write something like that myself :)

Comment: How do you name your test methods? Do they contain the name of the method your are testing?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Yes, they do. In the question I mention the exact convention these names follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After working a lot with tests, I've come to realize that (at least for me) having all those restrictions bring a lot of problems in the long run, rather than good things. So instead of using "Names" and conventions to determine that, we've started using code. Each project and each class can have any number of test projects and test classes. All the test code is organized based on what is being tested from a functionality perspective (or which requirement it implements, or which bug it reproduced, etc...). Then for finding the tests for a piece of code we do this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyFunctionalityTests
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> TestedClasses()
    {
        // We can find the tests for a class, because the test cases references in some special method.
        return new []{typeof(SomeTestedType), typeof(OtherTestedType)};
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestRequirement23423432()
    {
        // ... test code.
        this.TestingMethod(someObject.methodBeingTested); //We do something similar for methods if we want to track which methods are being tested (we usually don't)
        // ... 
    }
}
```

We can use tools like resharper "usages" to find the test cases, etc... And when that's not enough, we do some magic by reflection and LINQ by loading all the test classes, and running something like `allTestClasses.where(testClass => testClass.TestedClasses().FindSomeTestClasses());`
You can also use the TearDown to gather information about which methods are tested by each method/class and do the same.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with some interesting ideas about methods tracking. Not sure if I want to abandon all conventions - I'll probably try and develop some tool that would automatically synchronize test projects with their "real" counterparts.

Comment: It's like a test database! I like it!

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep class and test locations in sync when moving the code:

- Move the code to a uniquely named temporary namespace
- Search for references to that namespace in your tests to identify the tests that need to be moved
- Move the tests to the proper new location
- Once all references to the temporary namespace from tests are in the right place, then move the original code to its intended target

One strength of end-to-end or behavioral tests is the tests are grouped by requirement and not code, so you avoid the problem of keeping test locations in sync with the corresponding code.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding VS extensions that associate code to tests, take a look at Visual Studio's Test Impact. It runs the tests under a profiler and creates a compact database that maps IL sequence points to unit tests. So in other words, when you change the code Visual Studio knows which tests need to be run.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll certainly take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

One unit test project per project is the way to go. We have tried with a mega unit test project but this increased the compile time.

To help you refactor use a product like [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) or [code rush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/).

Comment: Yes, I am already using Resharper, but it helps only partially when renaming methods. It tries to find places in a solution where it thinks the method is used, but there are still many false positives, especially with common method names. I am looking for something more automatic and less time-consuming.

Comment: Resharper and VS can help you rename namespaces, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360320/refactor-namespace-in-visual-studio

Comment: That's right. But in my case, it would only rename a namespace of e.g. `CustomerRepository` and not `CustomerRepositoryTests`, which is exactly what I am after.

Comment: You could create X new test projects with the correct new namesapces and then move the tests into the relevant new test project.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some clever way of organizing unit tests that would still
>   allow me to locate tests for a specific code quickly

Resharper have some good short cuts that allows you to search file or code

As you said for class CustomerRepository  their is a test CustomerRepositoryTests

R# shortcut shows inpput box for what you find in you case you can just input CRT and it will show you all the files starting with name have first as Capital C then R and then T

It also allow you do search by wild cards such as CR* will show you the list of file CustomerRepository and CustomerRepositoryTests

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I don't really see how it could help me with my problems; the sentence you are quoting continues with *and at the same time lend itself more towards refactoring?* - and that is the thing I need to solve :)